# .JS file in SPFX WebPart: Module parse failed: Unexpected token You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react

I have created an SPFx project with reactJS. I am using .jsx extension - functional components.

Now, the spfx webpart is already working fine, but I saw a material kit that I want to reuse its components.

When I referenced the components, I am presented with this error

> [SPLoaderError.loadComponentError]:
> ***Failed to load component (WebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load entry point from component WebPart). Original error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (30:4)
> File was processed with these loaders:
> ./node_modules/source-map-loader/index.js
> You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

[image]

It seems that I cannot use the "footer" tag?

[image]

Here's the 3rd screenshot, I created a .js component that I tried to insert in my WebPart.tsx but still the same error.

[image]

Comment: I have tried adding `<footer>` in my .tsx component, in my project and it works just fine. What if you remove all child components from `<footer>` and the `className`? Just to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: I already tried using <footer> in my other component and is working, however, if I use the Footer.js component from Material Kit, the error above appears. 
I already commented the child components inside <footer className={footerClassess}> but still the error in the 1st screenshot exists

Comment: is it really important to use the `footer` tag? maybe it's OK to use a good old div instead? Second question: is it possible to modify the Footer.js file to give this component a different name? maybe the names somehow collide (although that's not supposed to happen)

Comment: good idea. I just tried replacing footer tag with div, however, it seems that the cause is not really in the <footer> the same error as the 1st screenshot but arrow is pointing to the <div className={footerClasses}>, my guess is as wht the error is showing that I need additinal load to handle the result, but I am not sure how to do that. been searching google for quite some time now.

Comment: I also tried creating my own component with a .JS file extension, even if it is just a simple component that displays a <p> tag, the same error is showing. it seems there's a problem if I use .js components

Comment: So the problem is somehow related to the classNames() function?  Can you check what it returns? And maybe share its code?

Comment: not really on the classNames(), but I think because the component that I created is a .js file extension, and my WebPart is .tsx, it seems there's a conflict. 

Let's rule out the  code in my 2nd screenshot in my post, here's the simple component that I just created

`import React from 'react'

const TestFooterComponent = ()=> {

  return(
    <>
      <p>TEST FOOTER COMPONENT</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default TestFooterComponent;

see 3rd screenshot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123010/discussion-between-aventus-and-denis-molodtsov).